# Применение результатов сегментации изображения для дальнейшего анализа

Tags: алгоритм, opencv, распознавание, машинное-обучение

Возник ряд вопросов в изучении сегментации и кластеризации объектов на растровых изображениях. Я опишу поэтапно что делаю для решения конкретной задачи, на некоторых этапах возникают вопросы, хотелось бы получить помощь.

Допустим, нужно выделить на топографической карте однородные объекты(например деревья), а далее выделить на этой карте леса(скопления деревьев)

1. Выделили несколько деревьев вручную, это образцы, посчитали среднюю
   статистику по этим сегментам, получаем усредненый объект(образец).
2. Провели сегментацию изображения, и далее нужно отсечь из всех
   сегментов те, которые наиболее близки по характеристикам к
   усредненному образцу

   Вопросы на этом этапе: *Я делал это задав
   некоторые пороги значений, и далее последовательным обходом по всем
   сегментам, выделял схожие( на низкокачественных изображениях плохие
   результаты ). Правильный ли это подход? Если нет то какой будет вернее?
   Можно ли проделать такое же используя алгоритмы кластеризации?*
3. После получения этих сегментов, нужно выделить их на новый растр, и
       уже на нем, на основе информации об этих сегментах, провести
       кластеризацию, дабы выделить леса.

   *Допустим на карте есть лес проросший так, если бы он выглядел на карте в форме подковы, или кольца, или даже как персекающиеся подкова и кольцо. 
   Как выделить такие кластеры наиболее точно? Использовать расстояние Махаланобиса? Какие еще есть методы?*

*По расстоянию Махаланобиса тоже ничего внятного не написано, только в общих чертах, откуда конкретно брать например данные для матрицы ковариации?*

Answer (score 3):

По п.2: если изображение не битовое, то Ваш подход неправильный. Должна быть первичная обработка сигнала, в данном случае это перемножение изображения на маску дерева в скользящем окне (коэффициенты маски надо отнормировать так, чтобы произведение маски на себя было единицей или удобной константой). Если присутствуют цветовые каналы, то надо просуммировать такие произведения по всем доступным каналам с весами. Веса подобрать эмпирически.

После первичной обработки каждому элементу изображения будет соответствовать определённая цифра. Её-то и надо сравнивать с порогом.

По п.3. После пороговой обработки у Вас уже есть битовое поле с деревьями. И хотя расстояния Махалонобиса - не моя епархия, но других данных для них быть не может.